# I get this error in my code 'NSInvalidArgumentException',

Tags: ios, xcode

```
2015-02-03 22:44:17.468 descuentos[1430:55158] -[UIButton value]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fde78d95440
2015-02-03 22:44:17.472 descuentos[1430:55158] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIButton value]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fde78d95440'
*** First throw call stack:
```

How can I fix this error? I think this is a thread error.

Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)TipsSlider:(id)sender {

     UISlider *slider = sender;
     float valorFloat = slider.value;
     int valInt = (int)valorFloat;
    _dataSlider.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%d", valInt];

}

 - (IBAction)calcular:(id)sender {

     UISlider *slider = sender;
     float valorFloat = slider.value;
     int valInt = (int)valorFloat;
      _dataSlider.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%d", valInt];




    float  valorIn= [[entrada text]  floatValue];
    float resultado = (valorFloat / 100) * valorIn;

    NSString *resultadoFinal = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%4.2f",resultado];
    _salidaResultado.text = resultadoFinal;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! See [My App crashed. Now what?](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1)

Comment: Probably you connected the outlet to UIButtons. And when you click on it the app is crashing. Because of that conversion.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have connected an IBAction from a UIButton when you intended to use a UISlider.

You then assign the sender of the action (which is a button) to a slider and try to access its "value", only that UIButton instances do not respond to a "value" message and that's why you get the crash.

So, make sure you are "ctrl+dragging" from a slider in IB.